# how to automatically click search button in google visual basic . net

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with textbox, button and a tabcontrol.

in the button I have this code :

```
[Dim browser As New WebBrowser()
TabPage1.Controls.Add(browser)
browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
browser.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.google.com"))]
```

The code above works, but I need to be able to search from my textbox and when I click the button it will take me to google and then automatically enter's the word I searched for in my textbox and then clicks the search on google button. I tried this but it does not work. Thanks

```
Dim textElement. As HtmlElement = browser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")(0)
textElement.SetAttribute("value", textbox.text")
Dim btnElement As HtmlElement = browser.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnG")(0)
btnElement.InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: GetElementsByName returns a collection of elements, for which you've to iterate through each html element and then invoke after checking it's id

Comment: @RahulRajan The sample code he posted actually just grabs the first index from the array, so it should be OK based on Google's current web page layout and naming. Using GetElementsById would be a better choice if possible.

Comment: Yup, I'd recommend GetElementsById anytime. Atleast in this case

Comment: @RahulRajan While scraping another website in a reliable way always entails some amount of risk, I'm not sure in this instance whether relying on an id or a form name is better -- which one changes more often I wonder?

Comment: Why not pass your user's search from your text box directly to the browser control - `browser.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & yourUserSearchText))` and forget about any clicking tricks?

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to search in Google Browser with the text the User wanted and by adding the code below to the Button Click Event it did what I wanted.

> Code:

```
Dim sInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=" & TXT_Entidade.Text)

Try
    Process.Start(sInfo)
Catch ex As Exception
    Process.Start("iexplore.exe", sInfo.FileName)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set focus to the textElement before clicking the button.

```
textElement.Focus()
```

Otherwise, the page won't run the search apparently.

You can see this by trying the same basic steps you've got above in the Console window. They won't work until the field has had focus (from my testing).

(I also used the mshtml type library so that the click function was directly exposed in the full code below)

```
Imports mshtml

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        web.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim textElement As HtmlElement = web.Document.All.GetElementsByName("q")(0)
        textElement.SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
        textElement.Focus()
        Dim btnElement As HTMLButtonElement =
            CType(web.Document.All.GetElementsByName("btnG")(0).DomElement, 
                HTMLButtonElement)
        btnElement.click()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this in your button click handler...

```
browser.navigate("https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+textbox.Text)
```

This will search Google for the text in your Text Box.
You can search without "automatically clicking the search button" and you do not have to set the value in the text element of the html. This works for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide some information about the method and description for your answer.